# Is it possible to have nested functions without closures?

Tags: closures, language-agnostic, language-design

My understanding of closures so far is that they combine "open" functions with their surrounding scope, essentially making them closed expressions.

I've seen several examples of how this is implemented in Javascript, most of them using nested functions to create an outer and inner scope and show how the language creates a "snapshot" of the surrounding scope for the inner function.

However, I know there's languages that don't implement closures, for example C. In this particular case, there's also no (native) support for nested functions, so it seems that it is not possible to replicate the "inner" and "outer" cases from JavaScript - and as far as I know, due to this, not having closures doesn't become a important problem.

However, would it be possible for a language to have nested functions and **still have no closures?** Or does one implies on the another?

Comment: Pascal had nested functions and I don't think it had closures. Nested functions in Pascal shared the stack frame, I believe. That means they couldn't 'outlive' the enclosing function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of a "closure" is only meaningful when a function can be executed from outside of the scope in which it's declared.

In languages without first-class functions, i.e., where functions can't be passed around or assigned to variables, you could still have nested functions, but they couldn't be used as closures.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the area to play scoping concept in javascript...as you know in java we use **class components** mostly then we achieve parents functionality's using **inheritance** but javascript is a **weird language**...so **we can't achieve** closures with out nested function